# Craft 3: Custom "Set Password Form" not working

Tags: craft3, form, password

I'm trying to make a custom page for setting a new password. I found the following in the docs: https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/examples/set-password-form.html

I created a file called `setpassword.twig` in my templates folder but it isn't shown when I click the link in the email.

What am I doing wrong? Needs the template to be somewhere else?

Comment: From the link, did you set the [setPasswordPath](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/config/config-settings.html#setpasswordpath) config setting as well?

Comment: Yes, but I set it to the default value, which is 'setpassword'

Comment: Are you testing with a non-admin user?

Comment: @Mijingo you are right, it works for non-admin users. Thanks for pointing that out.